# Loading Big HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very big html file, size of dom element is more than 1500. Basically there are many div elements and we load all these divs. However we don't display all these divs at the beginning. Is there a way I can load these divs on demand?

Comment: Have a look at AJAX.

Comment: I think what Oded is implying is that you should try to choose someone's answer as having helped you with your question. A green tick will appear next to their answer once you have selected it as your answer. If you do not choose an answer as having helped you, people will be disinclined to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean 1500 elements.

Looks into AJAX and lazy loading, so loading the content when the user gets towards it or its visible.

http://www.thewebsqueeze.com/web-design-tutorials/introduction-to-ajax-with-jquery.html

http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/08/10/lazy-loading-jquery-ui-ajax-play

http://cflove.org/2010/09/how-to-build-a-lazyload-ondemand-load-with-jquery.cfm

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

A more important question, do you actually need 1500 elements, seem like a lot. Is there no way you can either reduce the number of elements, use pagination or separate pages?

## EXAMPLE

```
function loadHeads() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/mycontent.html",
    context: document.body
  }).done(function(data) { 
    $("#container").html(data);
  });
}

$("#container").bind("mouseleave", function() {
   $(this).empty();
});

<div id="head" onclick="loadHeads()"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, for your quick reply .Basically it's an app where a user can create a replica of himself by selecting different objects, such as when the user clicks on head different head shapes are loaded, when he click on shirts all the shirt images are displayed which are in divs and so on. Earlier we had seperate html files for every objects, but scrolling did not work and we were forced to write all the divs in the same html.

Comment: I think the answer therefore is to only load the elements you need when you need them, and then destroy them when they are hidden. 

So if a user click the head, it shows other heads, but when this close the elements are deleted. These elements can be loaded via AJAX from a different file.

Comment: How can we do that? You mean to say dynmically load divs?

Comment: Yes, look into jQuery and loading content via AJAX. You would essential load content into a holding div, and when its finished with destroy the content in this holding div, I will update the answer th reflect this.